# Type '{ recipe: null; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Recipe'

Tags: typescript, next.js

Working on a ChatGPT-integrated app that sources recipes from a user's input ingredients. I'm trying to render a Recipe "Card" component after getting the response back from CGPT (which I've prompted to return as JSON), however I'm getting the above-titled error when trying to pass the recipe state to the Recipe component...I'm assuming I'm getting {recipe: null} because it doesn't exist / doesn't get set until after the user has sent through their chosen ingredients...how can I conditonally pass down the recipe state once it's formulated? Code below:

Component that holds all the search logic

```
'use client'
import { useState } from "react";
import  Recipe  from './components/Recipe'


const Recipes = () => {

  const [ingredients, setIngredients] = useState('')
  const [recipe, setRecipe ] = useState(null)
  const [ingredientList, setIngredientList] = useState('')
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(1)
  

  const getRecipe = async function getRecipe(e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>){
    e.preventDefault()
    setIngredientList(ingredients)
    setIsLoading(2)
    const response = await fetch('/api/recipes', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: ingredients
    })
    const recipe = await response.json()
    if (recipe){
      setRecipe(recipe)
      setIngredients('')
      console.log(recipe)
    }
  }

  return (
    <>
    <div>

      <div>
      <form onSubmit={getRecipe} >
        <input className=" bg-blue-600 text-black" type='text' placeholder='add your ingredients' value={ingredients} onChange={(e) => {setIngredients(e.target.value)}}/>
        <button type="submit">get recipes</button>
      </form>
      </div>

      {/* <div>
        <h1>Ingredients List</h1>
        {ingredientList}
      </div> */}

      {/* <div>
        {isLoading===2 && !recipe ? "loading" : recipe}
      </div> */}

      <Recipe recipe={recipe}/>

    </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Recipes;
```

Recipe "Card" Component

```
import React from 'react'

type Recipe = {
    title: string,
    servings: string,
    ingredients: string[]
    instructions: string[]

}

const Recipe = (recipe: Recipe) => {

  return (
    <div className='p-10'>
        <div>
            <h1>Recipe Name</h1>
            {recipe.title}
        </div>


        <div>
            <h1>Instructions</h1>
            <ul>
                {recipe.instructions?.map((instruction: string) => <li>{instruction}</li>)}
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>
  )
}

export default Recipe
```

I tried to move the type Recipe to the search logic component but that didn't do anything; I believe the issue is trying to pass something down that doesn't exist yet...maybe conditionally render the whole Recipe Card component so it doesn't show up unless there is DEFINITELY a recipe? I'm a Typescript newbie so any help is appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that, on first load the `const [recipe, setRecipe ] = useState(null)` sets the `recipe` to null for the first time it goes through rendering and then fails.
You do seem to have code that already checks for it but commented out

```
      {/* <div>
        {isLoading===2 && !recipe ? "loading" : recipe}
      </div> */}
```

So you could use change it to show the component or add the check before the component:

```
return (
// ...
      <div>
        {isLoading===2 && !recipe ? "loading" : <Recipe recipe={recipe}/>} // solution 1
      </div>

      {recipe && <Recipe recipe={recipe}/>} // solution 2
// ...
)
```